# 500 Server Error from charge-credit-card.php Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I am using the php spl package for the Authorize.net SDK. I verified that SimpleXML, cURL, and JSON are all installed on the server and PHP 5.6+ is being used.

I have verified that the SDK is building the $request object `$request->setTransactionRequest( $transactionRequestType);`

The returned object using print_r

```
net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CreateTransactionRequest Object ( [transactionRequest:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CreateTransactionRequest:private] => net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType Object ( [transactionType:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => authCaptureTransaction [amount:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => 151.51 [currencyCode:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [payment:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => net\authorize\api\contract\v1\PaymentType Object ( [creditCard:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\PaymentType:private] => net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CreditCardType Object ( [cardCode:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CreditCardType:private] => [isPaymentToken:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CreditCardType:private] => [cryptogram:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CreditCardType:private] => [cardNumber:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CreditCardSimpleType:private] => 4111111111111111 [expirationDate:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CreditCardSimpleType:private] => 2038-12 ) [bankAccount:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\PaymentType:private] => [trackData:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\PaymentType:private] => [encryptedTrackData:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\PaymentType:private] => [payPal:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\PaymentType:private] => [opaqueData:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\PaymentType:private] => ) [profile:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [solution:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [callId:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [authCode:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [refTransId:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [splitTenderId:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [order:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => net\authorize\api\contract\v1\OrderType Object ( [invoiceNumber:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\OrderType:private] => 101 [description:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\OrderType:private] => Golf Shirts ) [lineItems:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => Array ( [0] => net\authorize\api\contract\v1\LineItemType Object ( [itemId:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\LineItemType:private] => Shirts [name:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\LineItemType:private] => item1 [description:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\LineItemType:private] => golf shirt [quantity:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\LineItemType:private] => 1 [unitPrice:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\LineItemType:private] => 20.95 [taxable:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\LineItemType:private] => ) ) [tax:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => net\authorize\api\contract\v1\ExtendedAmountType Object ( [amount:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\ExtendedAmountType:private] => 4.5 [name:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\ExtendedAmountType:private] => level 2 tax name [description:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\ExtendedAmountType:private] => level 2 tax ) [duty:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [shipping:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [taxExempt:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [poNumber:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => 15 [customer:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CustomerDataType Object ( [type:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CustomerDataType:private] => [id:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CustomerDataType:private] => 15 [email:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CustomerDataType:private] => foo@example.com [driversLicense:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CustomerDataType:private] => [taxId:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CustomerDataType:private] => ) [billTo:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CustomerAddressType Object ( [phoneNumber:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CustomerAddressType:private] => [faxNumber:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CustomerAddressType:private] => [email:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\CustomerAddressType:private] => [firstName:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => Ellen [lastName:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => Johnson [company:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => Souveniropolis [address:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => 14 Main Street [city:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => Pecan Springs [state:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => TX [zip:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => 44628 [country:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => USA ) [shipTo:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType Object ( [firstName:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => Bayles [lastName:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => China [company:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => Thyme for Tea [address:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => 12 Main Street [city:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => Pecan Springs [state:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => TX [zip:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => 44628 [country:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\NameAndAddressType:private] => USA ) [customerIP:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [cardholderAuthentication:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [retail:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [employeeId:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [transactionSettings:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => [userFields:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\TransactionRequestType:private] => ) [merchantAuthentication:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\ANetApiRequestType:private] => net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType Object ( [name:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType:private] => *******[transactionKey:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType:private] => ***********[sessionToken:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType:private] => [password:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType:private] => [impersonationAuthentication:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType:private] => [fingerPrint:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType:private] => [mobileDeviceId:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType:private] => ) [refId:net\authorize\api\contract\v1\ANetApiRequestType:private] => ref1453823618 )
```

The error seems to happen at:

```
$controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
$response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( \net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
```

Commenting either out one at a time causes the 500 error, if both removed it finishes the script.

The full script:

```
<?php
  require '../../autoload.php';
  use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
  use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;
  define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog");


  // Common setup for API credentials
  $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
  $merchantAuthentication->setName("*********");
  $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey("******************");
  $refId = 'ref' . time();

  // Create the payment data for a credit card
  $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
  $creditCard->setCardNumber( "4111111111111111" );
  $creditCard->setExpirationDate( "2038-12");
  $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
  $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);

  // Order info
  $order = new AnetAPI\OrderType();
  $order->setInvoiceNumber("101");
  $order->setDescription("Golf Shirts");

  // Line Item Info
  $lineitem = new AnetAPI\LineItemType();
  $lineitem->setItemId("Shirts");
  $lineitem->setName("item1");
  $lineitem->setDescription("golf shirt");
  $lineitem->setQuantity("1");
  $lineitem->setUnitPrice(20.95);
  $lineitem->setTaxable(false);

  // Tax info 
  $tax =  new AnetAPI\ExtendedAmountType();
  $tax->setName("level 2 tax name");
  $tax->setAmount(4.50);
  $tax->setDescription("level 2 tax");

  // Customer info 
  $customer = new AnetAPI\CustomerDataType();
  $customer->setId("15");
  $customer->setEmail("foo@example.com");

  // PO Number
  $ponumber = "15";
  //Ship To Info
  $shipto = new AnetAPI\NameAndAddressType();
  $shipto->setFirstName("Bayles");
  $shipto->setLastName("China");
  $shipto->setCompany("Thyme for Tea");
  $shipto->setAddress("12 Main Street");
  $shipto->setCity("Pecan Springs");
  $shipto->setState("TX");
  $shipto->setZip("44628");
  $shipto->setCountry("USA");

  // Bill To
  $billto = new AnetAPI\CustomerAddressType();
  $billto->setFirstName("Ellen");
  $billto->setLastName("Johnson");
  $billto->setCompany("Souveniropolis");
  $billto->setAddress("14 Main Street");
  $billto->setCity("Pecan Springs");
  $billto->setState("TX");
  $billto->setZip("44628");
  $billto->setCountry("USA");

  //create a transaction
  $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
  $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType( "authCaptureTransaction"); 
  $transactionRequestType->setAmount(151.51);
  $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);
  $transactionRequestType->setOrder($order);
  $transactionRequestType->addToLineItems($lineitem);
  $transactionRequestType->setTax($tax);
  $transactionRequestType->setPoNumber($ponumber);
  $transactionRequestType->setCustomer($customer);
  $transactionRequestType->setBillTo($billto);
  $transactionRequestType->setShipTo($shipto);

  $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
  $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
  $request->setRefId( $refId);
  $request->setTransactionRequest( $transactionRequestType);
  $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
  $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( \net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);

  if ($response != null)
  {
    $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();

    if (($tresponse != null) && ($tresponse->getResponseCode()=="1") )   
    {
      echo "Charge Credit Card AUTH CODE : " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
      echo "Charge Credit Card TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo  "Charge Credit Card ERROR :  Invalid response\n";
    }

  }
  else
  {
    echo  "Charge Credit card Null response returned";
  }
?>
```

Thank you for any help or advice on establishing the connection properly

Comment: The issue I was having was the fact that the SPL Autoloader SDK package does not come packaged without all of the dependent libraries. 

I solved this by getting a new server with shell (SSH) access and educating myself on Composer to install their package automatically. Once done, it worked like a charm and now I can finally get to work!